# iOS SpriteKit Get All nodes in a current scene and make the application universal.

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

Hi, I am new to sprite kit framework I just wanted to know two things:

**1)** How to get all the SKSprite Nodes in a current scene? 
**2)** How to make the application universal i.e it will run on iPhone 3.5", iPhone 4" and on iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. in Scene.m, you can use `self.children` to get all the SKSprite Nodes
2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

Comment: Your answer to 1. seems not really answering the question or is it? The children of the scene can have children again, so self.children will not give you a full list of all nodes in the scene, but only of those who are children of the scene....

Answer (score 0):

While the second part of your answer is too broad, I can understand where you're coming from, as it's a bit overwhelming trying to figure out how to support all of the different screen sizes. But for other new developers who come across a similar overly broad question, if you are simply looking to have your scene fit in the different screen resolutions, and for the time being want to ignore the concept of multiple image resolutions and asset catalogs, one place to start is with handling the size of your scene and its scale mode:

In your viewController you could do something like this. It's a bit heavy handed, but designed to show the distinctions:

```
//we'll set what we want the actual resolution of our app to be (in points)
//remember that points are not pixels, necessarily
CGSize sceneSize = CGSizeMake(320, 568);

//check if this is an ipad, this means the screen has 2x the points
//it also means that the resolution is different than the iphone 5
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    sceneSize = CGSizeMake(sceneSize.width * 2, sceneSize.height * 2);
}


SKView *skView = (SKView*)self.view;
self.mainPrimaryScene = [[PrimaryScene alloc] initWithSize: sceneSize forSKView:skView];

//by setting the scale mode to fit, it takes the size of the scene
//and ensures that the entire scene is rendered on screen, in the correct ratio
self.mainPrimaryScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
//you can check out all the other scale modes if you want to fill, etc
    mainPrimaryScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

}

[skView presentScene:mainPrimaryScene];
```